# Dataflow writing to datastore poor performance?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Lately I have updated my dataflow apache beam pipeline to the latest version, my pipeline writes a huge amount of data. The pipeline before apache beam version update from 2.27 to 2.41 takes about 8 min to finish executing while after the update it takes more than 30 min to finish executing.

***Before the Update***

[image]

***After the update***

[image]

The `Enforce ramp-up through throttling` step wasn't shown before updating the pipeline version.

**Update:**
As mentioned in the [Apache Beam changes on updates](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/CHANGES.md) in version **2.32.0** that:

DatastoreIO: Write and delete operations now follow automatic gradual ramp-up, in line with best practices (Java/Python)

Where I think that the latency in writing occurs because of this update!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked with the team and generally speaking that's the expected behavior. The settings for the IO have those as standard settings to follow [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#ramping_up_traffic) for ramp-up, and not using it is possible, but discouraged.

[DatastoreV1 docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.html) can provide for further guidance:

> Write and delete operations will follow a gradual ramp-up by default in order to protect Cloud Datastore from potential overload. This rate limit follows a heuristic based on the expected number of workers. To optimize throughput in this initial stage, you can provide a hint to the relevant PTransform by calling withHintNumWorkers, e.g., DatastoreIO.v1().deleteKey().withHintNumWorkers(numWorkers). While not recommended, you can also turn this off via .withRampupThrottlingDisabled().

Comment: If my project was running without gradual ramp-up what issues will caused if I used `.withRampupThrottlingDisabled()` while writing to datastore? @Bruno Volpato

Comment: `.withRampupThrottlingDisabled()` should bring the behavior back to the previous version. It will likely have more parallel requests to Datastore and will not try to find a sweet spot for the throughput -- but if you have a better experience using it, I'd say you can go for it. Maybe if the dataset is large enough and you get performance/availability degradation, enabling the ramp-up will be healthier.

Comment: what are the consequences for not using ramp-up? @Bruno Volpato

Comment: I honestly don't know, it might be good to hint to Datastore to gradually take load instead of very large batches once in a while. A good reading on why something like that would is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control (e.g., finding a good throughput instead of trying too many things at once and failing).